# Use readthedocs to compile a latex git repository

Tags: python, latex

I really like [readthedocs](https://readthedocs.org/) and I'm using it in my python projects.

I've got a repo containing only latex files and was wondering if readthedocs is able to compile it to pdf or if there are other services who could do this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs.html) to readthedocs docs, they use Sphinx as generator, which can generate PDF from reStructuredText (reST) within LaTeX output. As far as I know, the answer to your question is no, readthedocs cannot generate pdf from a repo of LaTeX files, regarless of all output format they have (including PDF), because Sphinx use reST as input format.

I don't know much about readthedocs (besides the quick search I made for this response), but you could try [Latex Online](https://latexonline.cc/) for your purpose if your repo is a Git one. Also, if you want to collaborate on and/or edit TeX files online, take a look at ShareLaTeX. Both are OSS and can be installed via Docker.